Injecting a repository class in a service class and then trying to initiate service class in test without passing a repository causes error (Laravel)
Say I have:
class SomeService implements SomeInterface
{
    public function __construct(private SomeRepository $repo)
    {}

    public function createSomething(array $data)
    {
    }
}

If I want to test this service class with PHPUnit I will get an error "too few arguments passed to SomeService::__construct()"
class SomeServiceTest {
    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->service = new SomeService;
    }

    // some tests using above service...
}

I see lots of examples of this all over the internet - but why when it causes this error?
Am I missing something? You don't want to have to pass the repo to the constructor in the test again.
Am I approaching this the wrong way?

Because new SomeService expects the class SomeRepository as its parameter. Not ideal but maybe you can create $repo = new SomeRepository() then pass $repo to your SomeService

Of course, you have to pass SomeRepository to SomeService.
$this->mock(SomeRepository::class, function($mock) {
    $mock->shouldReceive('')->...
});

$service = new SomeService(app(SomeRepository::class));

It may seem like this is resolved automatically in Laravel controllers, but that's because Laravel is doing it for you.
Normally, you have to pass values ​​to the constructor yourself.
